# Chosing drawing tools

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, html5-canvas, drawing

I create drawing application with HTML5 and JavaScript.I write code to draw(pencil and rectangle)

```
if(window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var canvas, context, canvaso, contexto;


  var tool;
  var tool_default = 'pencil';

  function init () {

    canvaso = document.getElementById('imageView');
    if (!canvaso) {
      alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
      return;
    }

    if (!canvaso.getContext) {
      alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
      return;
    }


    contexto = canvaso.getContext('2d');
    if (!contexto) {
      alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
      return;
    }


    var container = canvaso.parentNode;
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    if (!canvas) {
      alert('Error: I cannot create a new canvas element!');
      return;
    }

    canvas.id     = 'imageTemp';
    canvas.width  = canvaso.width;
    canvas.height = canvaso.height;
    container.appendChild(canvas);

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    var tool_select = document.getElementById('dtool');
    if (!tool_select) {
      alert('Error: failed to get the dtool element!');
      return;
    }
    tool_select.addEventListener('change', ev_tool_change, false);


    if (tools[tool_default]) {
      tool = new tools[tool_default]();
      tool_select.value = tool_default;
    }


    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
  }


  function ev_canvas (ev) {
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { 
      ev._x = ev.layerX;
      ev._y = ev.layerY;
    } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) {
      ev._x = ev.offsetX;
      ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }


    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
      func(ev);
    }
  }


  function ev_tool_change (ev) {
    if (tools[this.value]) {
      tool = new tools[this.value]();
    }
  }


  function img_update () {
        contexto.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }


  var tools = {};


  tools.pencil = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;


    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    };


    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        context.stroke();
      }
    };


    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
        img_update();
      }
    };
  };


  tools.rect = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
      tool.started = true;
      tool.x0 = ev._x;
      tool.y0 = ev._y;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (!tool.started) {
        return;
      }

      var x = Math.min(ev._x,  tool.x0),
          y = Math.min(ev._y,  tool.y0),
          w = Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
          h = Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0);

      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      if (!w || !h) {
        return;
      }

      context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
        img_update();
      }
    };
  };
```

But the problem is in the index file when choose a tool for drawing.

```
<p><label>Drawing tool: <select id="dtool">
        <option value="line">Line</option>
        <option value="rect">Rectangle</option>
        <option value="pencil">Pencil</option>
    </select></label></p>
```

This works, but i want buttons to be images, but when i make it with images it doesn't work

```
<input  type="image" src="images/pencil.ico" width="25" height="25" >
```

Please help me!
Thanks in advance

Comment: `it doesn't work` doesn't explain much...what specifically doesn't work?

Comment: Your problem seems to have nothing to do with the canvas or html5. As far as I can see you're simply trying to create a single-select control that shows images. Do I understand that correctly? Of so, can you update the question to only contain the relevant details?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><label>Drawing tool: <select id="dtool">
        <option value="line">Line</option>
        <option value="rect">Rectangle</option>
        <option value="pencil">Pencil</option>
    </select></label></p>
```

If i use this code, when select line ->draw a line
when select pencil ->start drawing

but when to the button apply image like this :

```
<div id="dtool">
<input  type="image" src="images/pencil.ico" value="pencil" width="25" height="25" >
<input  type="image" src="images/line.ico" value="line" width="25" height="25" >
<input  type="image" src="images/rectangle.ico" value="rectangle" width="25" height="25" >
</div>
```

whatever i choose doesn' work(doesn't draw).